# Default conjunction for couchdb-lucene

Tags: couchdb-lucene

It appears that the default conjunction for CouchDB-Lucene is `OR`:

```
artist:muse track:"feeling good"
```

Might return:

```
{ "artist": "Muse", "track": "Feeling Good", "score": 5.9 }
{ "artist": "Nina Simone", "track": "Feeling Good", "score": "1.2" }
```

How can I configure CouchDB-Lucene so that two statements like at the top here are considered to be `AND`'d together, rather than `OR`'d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my readme file at https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene/, you can use a parameter to change this;

```
default_operator
Change the default operator for boolean queries. Defaults to "OR", 
other permitted value is "AND".
```

That is;

```
?q="hello there"&default_operator="AND"
```

Comment: I knew I'd read it somewhere - don't know why I couldn't find it again! Thank you so much!